# What is wrong with my mysql update query? Affected Rows = 0

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to update an entry in my database.

My query is as follows:

```
UPDATE asc_student_appointment
SET 
RANDOM_ID = '5i0oqotp6stiri9awo9ptp0o5aeoqpta4awi3o-i',
STUDENT_ID = '123456789',
FIRST_NAME = 'Testy',
LAST_NAME = 'McTesterson',
RIT_EMAIL = 'test@test.edu',
PHONE_NUMBER = '555-555-5678',
DATE_OF_APPOINTMENT = '2013-10-31',
TIME_OF_APPOINTMENT = '4:00 PM',
STAFF_NAME = 'JOHN DOE',
ADMIN_EMAIL = 'admin@test.edu'
WHERE 
RIT_EMAIL = 'test@test.edu'
AND 
STUDENT_ID = '123456789'
```

Now.. I want to update the entry for `Testy` in the `asc_student_appointment` table with the data provided in the query. The query is executing correctly, however, 0 rows are being affected.

I know that `Testy` exists in the database, however I don't understand why his information is not being updated.. The query executes fine but changes no data.

Any help?

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause doesn't match, or no fields where updated.

Comment: Either of Where fields must not be there...

Comment: What happens when you run this query manually? (using phpMyAdmin or similar)?

Comment: Perhaps that data is exactly what's in the DB, hence 0 rows updated, or that user doesn't exist yet. You can use INSERT IGNORE to get around that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do a `SELECT` first to see if there is any row to update:

```sql
SELECT * from asc_student_appointment WHERE RIT_EMAIL = 'test@test.edu' AND STUDENT_ID = '123456789'
```

If there is no row, you will have to do an `INSERT` instead of `UPDATE`